# Asymptotic notation bound

Tags: big-o

GIVEN :  F(n) = big-oh(n) + Theta(n) + Big-Omega(n) .
question: What is correct option for asymptotic bound for f(n).
(please explain your answer.)

(a)   big-oh(n) ; 
(b)   Theta(n) ; 
(c)   Big-Omega(n) ; 
(d)   F(n) is Unbounded;

Comment: I don't think this question belongs on StackOverflow, and in any case the "ada" tag is completely inappropriate.

Comment: question is related to asymptotic notation - required in complexity calculation of an algorithm in Ada(analysis and design of algorithms).

Comment: The tag should reflect what the question is about.  If you use an "ada" tag, the question should be about the Ada language, the Ada compiler, Ada compiler tools, SPARK, or something related to Ada.  But if your question is about algorithm complexity, it's not relevant that you happened to be using Ada to code your algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big-Omega(n) because you need to find the maximum possible time that f(n) will take.